# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, ubuntu

Here are some necessary version related details of the packages I have installed on a dream-compute (godaddy) server machine with `Ubuntu 16.04` with root access

`Apache Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)`

`php version 7`

`mongo db version v3.2.10`    and

```
$ pecl search mongo 

.Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
mongo   1.6.14 (stable)       MongoDB database driver
mongodb 1.1.9 (stable)  1.1.9 MongoDB driver for PHP
```

I have set up a website that was previously running on a different server with `PHP 5.6` and an old mongo-php driver.

Previously I was using `MongoClient` class in the connection string but after some searching I changed it to `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` in my connection class of the php website.

I have also included `extension=mongodb.so` in the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` file

The rest of the website is working fine, only when i browse to a page which has a mongodb call at the back-end gives me the following error (from php error log file):

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::selectDB() in /var/www/html/iot/includes/class.abstract-data-collection.php:118
```

I am not an expert in linux and hence I am stuck here. Anyone have any idea what should I try to actually get to the problem, should I need to change the php code or is there anything I am missing in the configuration?

TA

Comment: Because `Manager` class has no `selectDB` method?

Comment: There is no __selectDB__ method in this class according to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php)

Comment: So, what should be the best/easiest option for me.. to replace methods with their appropriate substitutes (I am not even sure if its possible, can you please give an example) or to set up the server using previous versions of PHP/Mongo etc?

Comment: @CarlosCarucce
@u_mulder
For example, how to replace this piece of code:  
<br />
`$this->_connection = Connection::get(MONGO_DB_CONN_STRING);
$this->_db = $this->_connection->selectDB(MONGO_DB_NAME);
$this->_collection = $this->_db->selectCollection($this->getName());`